# Eclipse Luna + Photran doesn't stop on Breakpoints during debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, gdbserver, photran

Before this stupid program will explode my head to the 26th time...

I have

- Win 7
- Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 Build 20140612-0600
- Photran 8.2.1
- Cygwin Devel Packages gfortran + make  (used)
- MinGW with g95 (installed but not used because no make.exe)

So I downloaded the Hello World example, changed it a bit

```
 program HelloW
 implicit none
 integer i
 i=1
 print *,i
 print *, "Hello MPI World"
 i=i+1
 print *,i
 i=1000
 print *,i
 end program
```

1) So problem (or most probably a mega-feature) number one.
The default debuggers (Run->Debug Configuration->Debugger) **gdbserver** and **minGW gbd** don't work, because they need .gdbinit. I created an empty file .gdbinit, but it doesn't help.  I could find no info of what must be inside.

OK, no wonder that just another Eclipse feature doesn't work. Next one:

2) As debugger I chose **gdb/mi**. It seems to work without .gdbinit.
I set a break point in front of **integer i** line.
I start the debugger but it looks like it runs till the end of the program and suspends there (the last line **end program** is lighted green).
Now if I press **F5** it starts to move in the program step by step from the very beginning, but it needs 3 button presses to do 1 line. It first jumps forward, nothing happens, then it jumps back, and on the 3rd press it jumps forward again and execute the line (e.g. the variable **i** changes).
What the hell is that?

I used Fortran Compaq and Intel Visual Studio without any problems. Now I f**ck with these "free" programs for 2 weeks now, and nothing works properly. Starting from the outdated help in eclipse, to dead g95 compiler.

Comment: Are you debugging optimized executable?